# Trautonium, Martenot Waves

Tags: sound-effects

Hello everybody ! Do you know where I can find trautonium and martenot waves and theramin sound effects?

THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theremin:

http://www.sampleism.com/noisymichael/resonator

http://www.wavelore.com/products.php?product=WLEP

http://www.puremagnetik.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=364:mysterium&catid=77&Itemid=159

Answer (score 1):

[Ondes Martenot](http://www.soniccouture.com/en/products/28-ancient-rare-and-experimental/g27-ondes/)